# Word describing the law itself as opposed to its intended subjects

Tags: word-choice

When analyzing a law, one can discuss the "subjects" of the law; e.g., the subjects of a law that imposes a sales tax will be the merchants and/or buyers. But how would one refer to the substance of the law itself as a distinct entity? Using my previous example, I'm looking for a word that would complete this sentence: "The __ of this law is the imposition of a sales tax." The word "substance" seems a little too broad for this purpose, as the subjects of the law are also part of its substance.

[Note: I'm well aware that the above sentence could easily be reworded as something like "The law imposes a sales tax"; it's just an example to explain what kind of technical term I'm trying to find.]

Comment: You could talk about the "text" or the "reading" of the law.

Comment: The subjects are not included in the law's "text" or "reading"?

Comment: ratio: _n. In civil law. an account; a cause, or the giving of judgment therein._  How about "ratio"?

Comment: @kurkevan: Are you talking about an abstraction of the law's reading? If so then perhaps the word "object" is what you want. "The object of this law is the imposition of a sales tax."

Comment: "the ratio of the law" has 4,450,000 hits on Google Search; while, alas, "the ratio of this law" has only six hits.

Comment: @Robusto "object" is the closest thing so far, but not perfect, since it also carries the sense of objective/goal.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: ratio is indeed a technical term in civil law, shortened from the Latin *ratio decidendi*. Unfortunately the sense of 'cause' used is that of 'reason', so it doesn't really fit here.

Comment: I think this is General Reference/Too Localised. It just so happens that OP has ruled out "subject" because he's co-opted that to mean *the people governed by this law*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, the case I am dealing with refers to the subjects earlier, so I need a different word to emphasize the distinction between these two elements. It's not like I just arbitrarily decided to restrict the definition of "subject".

Comment: @Carlo_R.: that term works well, but only in technical, legal language. It would not be recognizable outside of that context (it may very well be the intended context of the OP so very worthwhile). But Google Search is again misleadingly misleading. I get "84,200,000 results", but then I go in a page or so and get "137 results". So before posting numbers, check to make sure it holds up. But your suggestion is worth a real answer (backed up by examples).

Comment: @kurkevan: I can only say is that in principle, all citizens are "subject to" all laws within any given jurisdiction, but it seems slightly odd to me to single out some and call them the "subjects" of any law in particular. Personally I'd just say there's a *sales tax law*, in respect of which merchants and/or buyers are *affected parties*. I must admit I don't follow your argument against "substance", but I suppose you could say the imposition of a sales tax is the *substance, focus, remit, ambit, scope, compass, purpose, whatever* of that law.

Comment: It is for those in the field of law to select, define and adopt a term. Voting to close as too localized.

Answer (score 3):

> The __ of this law is the imposition of a sales tax.

I would suggest one of [essence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essence), [pith](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pith), [gist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gist), [purpose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/purpose) or perhaps even [letter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/letter).

Comment: _ratio: n. In civil law. an account; a cause, or the giving of judgment therein._  coleopterist, how about "ratio"?

Comment: @Carlo_R. - Isn't this **English**.SE? :)

Comment: "Essence" is pretty good!